# shortening following jquery expression

Tags: jquery

Any suggestion on shortening following:

```
$('#btn1').html($('#btn1').html().replace('string 1', 'string 22'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename btn1 to b1

Comment: funny :-), so it can't be shortened?

Comment: not the way you're doing it.  if  you are doing this often you can create a function that shortens it.